# Can Kaspersky Rescue My Netbook?

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, anti-virus, netbook

My cute little pink netbook has apparently contracted something terrible from one of those dodgy foreign websites.  I would like to use the [Kaspersky Rescue CD](http://devbuilds.kaspersky-labs.com/devbuilds/RescueDisk/) to attempt to save it instead of wiping it clean.  I've successfully converted the live CD to a bootable USB and I've booted into the super awesome fun anti-malware environment.

**The problem that I am having is that Kaspersky doesn't want to load any drivers for my networking devices.**  A `lspci` shows me that it recognizes the devices as an

```
Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x 802.11abg Wireless PCI Express Adapater (rev 01)
```

and a

```
Ethernet Controller: Attansic Technology Corp. Device 1062 (rev c0)
```

And that all seems pretty legit, but I don't know what to `modprobe` to get these bad boys to start working so I can download the latest updates.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to finding the right drivers for these guys and where to put them on the ISO before I "reburn" the bootable USB?   Linux and me aren't that close on the playground for him to just tell me outright.  Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!

I can provide the `uname` and any other useful information about the Rescue environment or whatever else you need, but I'm not sure what's required here.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I'm not looking for a *nix distro to reformat with and I'm not looking to just reload Windows.  This is more of an academic interest than anything, as it seems useful to know how to load extra drivers on my Kaspersky Rescue Disk (preferred), or at least the latest updates so I don't need the network drivers (back-up plan).

**CLARIFICATION**: I have no problems compiling a new kernel and attempting to use it instead of the stock Kaspersky one, I'm just looking for what drivers I need to compile into my new one to get these bad boys up and running.  I'm fairly confident that drivers for these devices exist in Linux as I've installed Ubuntu on a netboot very similar to this one previously (well, that one was baby-blue, not pretty-pink).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about restauration and virus-cleaning, put a decent linux live usb just backup your files and reinstall windows ...

I have slowly switched to linux and I won't go back, for a netbook linux can do much more than windows but you will need to learn linux but you will do purely what you want after and a netbook is the best to learn linux cause they are almost no case that Windows simplicity can appeal you back ...

I would try Slitaz 2 just to see linux pure speed, Ubuntu to learn the basics and straight when you get confortable with it, you could use Chakra live cd to install Arch linux, you will have a hard time but you will maybe have this netbook for a lifetime up-to-date with decent software on it ...

Note: That's my personal opinion, not an obligation, make your choice !!!

Comment: I may have misrepresented myself somewhat: I do use Linux somewhat.  The point of my question was not to look for a distro to install on this netbook, but for help locating drivers and a place to put them so that this rescue environment may find them and properly use my network.  I have no interest in installing Linux on this netbook (the HP laptop beside it runs Ubuntu, and the Dell laptop beside that one runs FreeBSD); this one I want to run WinXP Pro.  I thank you for the suggestions nonetheless, but it's just not really what I'm looking for.